# Mixing Objective-C and Swift in static library

Tags: swift, objective-c, static-libraries

I have a project with static library which use only swift, but now I need to add some objective c classes. How to do it correctly? I tried to add bridging header and library compiles without errors, but when I try to use library in another project I get error "Failed to import bridging header 'path/to/my/header/libName-Bridging-Header.h'". Why do I get this error? Should I also somehow use same header in project along with library? Can I do it without bridging header ?

Comment: Is it a SwiftPM library, or an Xcode project static library target?

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Is there any solution on this?